# Solr: Is it possible to change date format for a specific field using only the Schema API?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I would like to specify the date format `dd/MM/yyyy` for a field of type `date`.
I know the following methods:

1. edit `schema.xml` and add the `datetimeformat="dd/MM/yyyy"` attribute to the `<field />` tag involved, but I haven't tested it. Or,
2. edit `solrconfig.xml` and add a `<str>dd/MM/yyyy</str>` tag to the processor of class `solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory`. I'm sure this works because I've personally tested it.

I would like to use the managed schema and the Schema API instead of editing `schema.xml`. This is handy and useful both in standalone and Cloud Solr.

In order to add a `date` field, I do as follows:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/test/schema -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '
{   
  "add-field":
  {
    "name":"mydate",     
    "type":"date",
    "stored":true, 
    "indexed":true
  }
}'
```

and to edit some field properties, like the `stored` property, I do:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '
{
  "replace-field":
  {
    "name":"mydate",
    "stored":false
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/test/schema
```

If I try to set `"datetimeformat":"dd/MM/yyyy"` during the creation or the edit of the fields, I get an error.

Is it possible to edit the date format using **only** the Schema API without editing any `*.xml` file?

### UPDATE

I tried this command without any success:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/test/config -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
{
  "update-updateprocessor" : 
  {
    "class": "solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory", 
    "name":"solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory",
    "format":["dd/MM/yyyy"]
  }
}'
```

The problem is that the original definition of `solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory` in `solrconfig.xml` is:

```
<processor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <arr name="format">
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</str>
    <str>yyyy-MM-dd</str>
  </arr>
</processor>
```

and it doesn't have a `name` attribute. If I omitt `"name"` attribute in the JSON request, Solr throws the error `'name' is a required field`. I tried various combinations but none worked: `"name":"solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"`, `"name":"ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"`, `"name":""`.

### UPDATE 2

Running `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/test/config` returns a JSON object. Here's a portion of it:

```
{
...
    "updateRequestProcessorChain":[{
    "name":"add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema",
    "":[{"class":"solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {
        "class":"solr.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory",
        "pattern":"[^\\w-\\.]",
        "replacement":"_"},
      {"class":"solr.ParseBooleanFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.ParseLongFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory"},
      {"class":"solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"}]}],
...
}
```

This means that `solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory` is a *type of* `updateRequestProcessorChain`. The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+API) states:

> The Config API does not let you create or edit `<updateRequestProcessorChain>` elements. However, it is possible to create `<updateProcessor>` entries and can use them by name to create a chain.

This means that it's not possible to add a specific date format to the existing `solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory` using Config API. I should create a custom update processor that does what I want, and so use the `add-updateprocessor` API with proper parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling on the horrific Solr documentation, I found a solution. The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+API) states:

> The Config API does not let you create or edit
>   `<updateRequestProcessorChain>` elements. However, it is possible to
>   create `<updateProcessor>` entries and can use them by name to create a
>   chain.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> You can use this directly in your request by adding a
>   parameter in the `<updateRequestProcessorChain>` for the specific update
>   processor called `processor=firstFld`.

This means that I have to add a custom update processor and invoke it **explicitly** when using the `/update` handler. So:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/test/config -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
{
  "add-updateprocessor" : 
  {
    "name" : "myCustomDateUpdateProcessor", 
    "class": "solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory", 
    "format":["dd/MM/yyyy"]
  }
}'
```

To load the data into `test` collection via the `/update/csv` handler, use this command:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update/csv?processor=myCustomDateUpdateProcessor&commit=true --data-binary @file.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

Note the presence of `processor=myCustomDateUpdateProcessor`, where `myCustomDateUpdateProcessor` is the update processor I created before. The processor is stored in `configoverlay.json` and not in `solrconfig.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of things confused here:

1. datetimeformat is for DataImportHandler mapping definition. There is no datetimeformat in schema file
2. If you are using managed schema, you don't actually have schema.xml, you have managed-schema file
3. If you are using recent Solr, you have [Config API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+API) to modify solrconfig.xml. Actually, differently from managed-schema, you modify a separate overlay.json file, but the end-result is the same.

So, you have to set the format in the UpdateRequestProcessor, but you can manage that via API (in the recent Solr).

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. My question was exactly about how to set the date format using API. Documentation lacks on that topic, or may be I didn't search enough..

Comment: BTW, I'll follow the link you posted to figure out how to correctly invoke API.

Comment: I updated my question with what I came up until now. The documentation is very criptic and incomplete IMHO. I come from PostgreSQL, which has a far more light, clear, consistent, complete, organic and well structured documentation. I tried using the `update-updateprocessor` request but probably it's meant for custom update processors and not for factory ones. So I still can't find a way to add `dd/MM/yyyy` to `solrconfig.xml`. Thank you for your time and help